# Node.js unsupported URL type "node:"

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I wrote my Discord bot on windows 10 64 bit
and I wanted to host it from an old pc. This pc has windows 7 32 bit. I have installed node but it does not start. Below is the error.

Error:

```
npm ERR! code EUNSUPPORTEDPROTOCOL
npm ERR! Unsupported URL Type "node:": node:events

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Host-Abk\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-10-23T08_47_
44_300Z-debug.log
```

Comment: node --version please

Answer (score 0):

Based on this error, I can assume (without the needed information) your Node.js version is not up to date. Try updating to v16.x.x. This is indicating the `node:events` module is treated as a URI, which it is not, it's a Node module prefix.